# Asynchronous Promise mechanism

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm studying Event Loop of node.js and javascript promises in detail, but I don't understand how promises are asynchronous.
For example, in this code

```
const fs = require("fs");

// Very slow function
const exec = () => {
  return new Promise((response) => {
    while (true) {
      if (parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000000) === 5) {
        break;
      }
    }
    response();
  });
};

exec().then(() => console.log("Exec finish!"));

fs.appendFile("file.txt", "Sample text", (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("File created!");
});
```

I expect the file creation before the end of exec function but it is not so.
Can you help me?

Comment: The `while` loop is keeping JavaScript busy, and the event queue is not served until the currently running code has completed. Instead of a `while` loop, use `setTimeout(response, 5000)`.

Comment: async functions are still executed synchronously until they reach an `await` or the end of the function. At that point, they yield to the execution and schedule the rest of the function to run later. Your function doesn't have any point where the function will pause until the very end. The busy wait via loop blocks the thread.

Comment: Promises are just a notification system.  They let you subscribe to a notification for completion or error.  The underlying operation that is being tracked by the promise is what determines whether things are asynchronous or not.  If the underlying operation is blocking (like your `while` loop), then the operation will be blocking and nothing the promise does changes that.  You don't program with busy loops in Javascript - you just don't - even when using promises.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is keeping JavaScript busy, and so none of the code below the `const exec =`  expression will execute. Only when the loop finishes, will the execution continue with the next statement. In other words, the callback passed to the Promise constructor is executed synchronously. Only when that code finishes executing, will the assignment to `exec` complete and will execution continue with the next statement below it.

So the file appending didn't even start while the loop was running.

You can get this to work with `setTimeout` instead of a busy loop:

```
const exec = () => {
  return new Promise((response) => setTimeout(response, 2000))
};
```

Now the call to `setTimeout` will not block the further execution of the code, including the `appendFile` call. This `setTimeout` call will have as effect that two seconds later the `response` callback is put on the event queue. If the file appending got to completion faster than 2 seconds, the callback passed to `appendFile` will be put on the event queue sooner, and so it will be picked up for execution before the `response` callback.